# PHP Automatically login and fill a form with data from URL

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, authentication

I have two software. I want to create a link in the first one to call and fill a form in the second one.

The second one is written in PHP (with CakePHP) and can be accessed by authenticate users. I need to automatically log the users in and fill the form  on click of the link.

I don't know how to do that?

I was thinking of this solution, but can you please tell me if you see a better one.
-The link will contain all information to login my user and all information to prefill the form
-The link will be dedicated to this action in my php application. It will automatically log my user in, put the form data in session and redirect to the form page.
-In the form page, if the session variable is not empty I will fill my form.

Please help me and tell me what do you think of this plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a route that log you automatically just pass in args your login/pw **encoded in md5** after you redirect to what you want.
I am not using the cake but maybe you need to adjust what I propose to fill your wish

Comment: @burzum Yes hashed ;) language abuse. HTTPS + md5 hash is maybe not this secure but what he want to do is not secure too. But your true maybe a better way exist ;)

Comment: I know it is not very secure but my 2 software have to communicate. I can't do everithing I want, because the soft where the link will be is written in ASP.NET and I can only create link on it. That's why I can only do GET. I will try to hash before my variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn the GET parameters into POST, that's all and it's dead easy.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get